# Reference designators and bill of materials?

Tags: digital-logic

If my schematic has 31 OR gates and 99 AND gates while using 
CD74HCT32 - High Speed CMOS Logic Quad Two-Input OR Gates

CD74HCT08 - High Speed CMOS Logic Quad 2-Input AND Gates
what would my reference designators and bill of materials look like? Below is the schematic: [image]

Comment: This is the sort of thing you might want to consider using a CPLD for, rather than putting 25 14-pin DIP packages on a board like it's 1969.

Comment: @pjc50 is it's '69..shouldn't the gates on the right be facing the other way?

Answer (score 2):

Usually when you have a component such as the ones you mentioned, they will have a schematic symbol for each of the four AND / OR gates per component. So for every CD74HCT32, say, there will be 4 OR gate symbols.
Typically they will be referenced by IC1A, IC1B, IC1C, IC1D, for each sub-part of the component. So IC1 is the designator for the whole component as will be found on the PCB layout (if there is one) and Bill of Materials. The suffix letters indicate that it is a sub-part of a whole part so it is easier to see on a schematic.
On the schematic, the sub-part labelled with 'A' will usually be the one that has the part number. and the rest of them will simply be the designator.

So, for 31  OR gates, the schematic will have \$\frac{31}{4}\$ sets of four designators. So you would have IC1A - IC7C actually connected in the circuit, and for completeness you would show the remaining IC7D on the schematic with the inputs grounded or connected to VCC. 
The BOM for these devices will simply be IC1 - IC7 are CD74HCT32, and won't show the suffix.

Same again for the 99 AND gates, you would have designators on the schematic from IC8A - IC32C (starting from IC8 to follow on from the OR gates...) and again, IC32D same as above.
BOM is the same again. 24 components as the CD74HCT08.

See below - it is easier to determine the function of a circuit this way compared to if you did it like a microcontroller or something.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzluix.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: so would i just put it on a separate paper like IC1A-IC7C or would I need to include it on the schematic somehow..?

Comment: These are CMOS devices: you never want to leave unused inputs floating. Tie them to ground or Vcc.

Comment: @SeMinPark I don't understand the question. In a schematic editor, you can make a custom component, of which you can create sub-parts, when you go to add the component to the schematic, it will allow you to place the sub-parts one at a time and automatically increment the part number and suffix.

Comment: This is my first digital logic class and I was just wondering how to make a reference designator and bill of materials. Above is the specific example I was given. All these answers seem far too sophisticated for my understanding.

Comment: @SeMinPark Well, when it comes to making the schematic on a schematic designer, it would be able to do it all automatically if it is set up properly.

Comment: @SeMinPark ... Imagine you are using the schematic and are troubleshooting the circuit. The PCB in front of you has the reference designators printed on the silkscreen next to the components. On the schematic, you NEED the reference designators (and pin numbers) beside or within the schematic symbols so you will know where to put the probes (etc.). You definitely do not want the designators on a separate sheet. You will however also need the reference designators on the bill of materials (BOM) &/or a parts placement list so somone (&/or a pick-and-place machine) will know how to build the PCB.

Comment: @SeMinPark ... Besides reference designators, you also need part numbers which are included on the schematic (next to or within the symbol), bill-of-materials and (usually) parts placement list. If the board is built by hand and the reference designators are included in the bill-of-materials, a parts placement list is not necessary (this usually also contains part locations for the pick-and-place machine).